# navigation or tabbar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am a Iphone-traniee.sir i want to create a main login screen having three options as sign up,sign in and forgot password.
i am confused that whether to use navigation or tab bar application for it and how?
please anyone can guide me?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A Tab-bar interface would be too clunky for this, as most users will likely have an account and know their credentials.  The best approach in my opinion would be to have the username/password entry and login screen as the main screen with a login button under the text fields and then two inconspicuous links using UILabels below the button that would bring up create account and forgot password.  These should be brought up ModalViewController style rather than NavigationViewController style, as they are a one-time thing the user would do and aren't part of the application usage flow.

Hope this helps,

-HT